# Extract files from zip within zip file in R

Tags: r, unzip

Is there a way to extract the contents of a zip file within another zip file?

For example, I have `myFile.zip` and inside is `moreStuff.zip`.  Is there a way I can extract the `moreStuff.zip` file to a directory without extracting the main zip file?

I'm using `unzip()` but it would be helpful to skip the middle step of unzipping the main file.

Comment: If the files were already zipped, then myFile.zip is not doing much, apart from keeping all zipped files together. Why are we trying to avoid this step?

Comment: The main zip is huge, whereas the zip I really need is tiny.  It takes forever to unzip the master.  It has tons of files and other zips I don't care about.

Comment: `unzip()` takes a `files` parameter. It you specify the path to the internal ZIP file you'll just get that extracted and can then unzip that file.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I didn't realize that, let me give it a try.